# How can I initialize a member const reference in a derived class, when I wish to call a base class constructor?

Tags: c++, class, reference, constants, derived

I cannot find this question even  being asked anywhere...so that makes me believe i'm doing something very wrong here...

Lets say I have a base class, A, with a constructor that takes in int parameter.
In my derived class, B, I wish to invoke that constructor but also initialize a member reference passed in B's constructor. How can i do this? I cannot find the syntax to add an initialization list if I call the base class constructor. Is this possible?

Lets say I have:

```
Class Object
{
   Object(){}
}

Class A
{
   A(int number) : m_number(number){}

public:
   int m_number;
}
```

Now, how would I initialize m_obj if i wish to call the non-default constructor of A?

e.g.

```
Class B : Class A
{
   B(int number, const Object& objRef) : A(number)
   {
       m_obj = objRef; //error, : must be initialized in constructor base/member  
                       // initializer list...but I cannot access an initializer list!!
   }

private: 
   const Object& m_obj;
}
```

as I said, my intent is probably all wrong here, but if it's valid, I cannot find any syntax examples on google..

go easy on me...:)

Comment: Also note that you can't "drop" constness of reference, so you'll have to either change the `m_obj` member to `const Object&` or change your constructor to take `Object&` instead of `const Object&`

Comment: @LihO, so lets say I wish to pass a non-const reference to a member function of this class, but I do not want the function to modify the object that is referenced? It is recommended that function parameters are passed as const reference, but would that mean the objects that are referenced must also be const?

Comment: The point is that if you pass a `const` reference, you should store it as a `const` reference. `private: Object& m_obj;` should be `private: const Object& m_obj;`.

Comment: updated reference to const

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the constructor's initialization-list:

```
B(int number, const Object& objRef) : A(number), m_obj(objRef)
{}
```

(Note, this is nothing to do with this being a subclass.  You always need to use the initialization list in order to initialize a member variable that's a reference.)

Comment: Thanks for this, it was driving me mad trying to find that syntax (i.e. comma after the Base class ctor).